# Alter Scripts in SQL - ORA 01735

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

I've tried searching this topic, and my searches led me to this format, which is still throwing an error. When I execute my script, I basically get a load of ORA-01735 errors for all my later statements. I had it done out differently, but googling led me to this format, which still doesn't work. Any tips?

```
CREATE TABLE table7
(
column1 int NOT NULL,
column2 int NOT NULL,
column3 int NOT NULL
)
/

ALTER TABLE table7

ADD(    pk1 PRIMARY KEY(column1),
    fk1 FOREIGN KEY(column2) REFERENCES Table1(column2),
    fk2 FOREIGN KEY(column3) REFERENCES Service(column3)
)
/
```

Comment: It looks like ORA-01735 is an ORACLE error code, so I added a tag for oracle.

Comment: "*Any tips?*" - the syntax is documented in detail in the manual. Doesn't hurt to read that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ADD` should surround each column definition.  You don't wrap a single `ADD` around 3 new columns.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2183462

For Primary Key and Foreign Key constraints you need the `CONSTRAINT` keyword.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html  Section on "adding constraints".

**EDIT:** This was the only thing that worked on the fiddle I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE table7
ADD (
      CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY (column1),
      CONSTRAINT fk1 Foreign Key (column2) REFERENCES Table1 (column2),
      CONSTRAINT fk2 Foreign Key (column3) REFERENCES Service (column3)
    )
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d2a3

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had it wrong originally, and after some googling, came across this example https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2148438

Don't know how I missed out on the Constraints keywords, but for some reason I thought they weren't necessary for FK and PKs. On a side note, that example uses just the one ADD? Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Killian Follow the example!!  I'm a MySQL/SQLServer dev ;-)  I just like to read docs sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
ALTER TABLE table7
ADD pk1 PRIMARY KEY(column1),
ADD fk1 FOREIGN KEY(column2) REFERENCES Table1(column2),
ADD fk2 FOREIGN KEY(column3) REFERENCES Service(column3)
```

See syntax and examples:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/alter-table.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/alter-table-examples.html

Comment: I can't get this to run in the Fiddle I was using (Oracle 11g).

Comment: Your links are for **MySQL**, that is not Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

ALTER TABLE table7
ADD (
      CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY (column1),
      CONSTRAINT fk1 Foreign Key (column2) REFERENCES Table1 (column2),
      CONSTRAINT fk2 Foreign Key (column3) REFERENCES Service (column3)
    )

it works for me .Thanks